# Samba AD DC - Directory entry for a shared folder

Tags: ldap, active-directory, shared-folders, samba4

Suppose that you have:

- a Linux machine (A) running a Samba AD DC,
- a Windows machine (B), with a shared folder `\\B\shared_folder`.

I would like to know if there is an entry in the directory for this shared folder.

If so, how can I search for it using for example the `ldapsearch` command-line tool?

I would like to visualize what information about that shared folder are stored in the directory.

Can I get a list of the shared directories in the network from the directory?

Comment: Does "_the directory_" refer to Windows Active Directory or a filesystem? If it's a filesystem do you mean on the remote Windows server or on the Linux client?

Comment: Hello. I was referring to a directory in the sense of Windows Active Directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only shares that are in AD are the ones in sysvol, all other shares on a Samba server are stored in the smb.conf, the Samba registry (if it is being used) or /var/lib/samba if you are using usershares. No idea where Windows stores them (probably the Windows registry, that has everything including the kitchen sink in it), but it definitely isn't in AD.

Comment: Thank you. So, there wouldn't be an entry in the directory for \\B\shared_folder. In the "Active Directory" Wikipedia article (2023.02.16), one can read: "A domain represents a database. That database holds records about network services-things like computers, users, groups and other things that use, support, or exist on a network. The domain database is, in effect, Active Directory." Please note the "other things that use, support, or exist on a network". That's very vague to me. To me, files and folders are such "other things [...]" that's why I was asking my question.

Comment: The 'other things' are dns records, dhcp records, the schema itself, schema extensions, things like that.